# How to implement Share (View only) functionality on content of the web page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, highcharts, share

I am creating a HTML/JavaScript/PHP application that authenticates users and shows its *highcharts* graphs.

Now I want to implement a *Share functionality*. A user should be able to share his graphs page with any other user with the functionality of a *View Only* access.

After searching so many things I am really stuck how to achieve this.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Check against the owner of the resource, and limit write/edit access only to that owner. The implementation will entirely depend on your application and auth strategy.

Essentially, you want to limit all requests except your GET request. As long as your GET request can only read the resource.

Comment: Is this question about architecture or implementation? What is your exact problem? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and refine your question. We're happy to help, but you need to invest some effort, too.